# Variable z can't access variable x from a different function

Tags: c++

Looking at the code I've provided, I am trying to make it so that z = x

but it doesn't work since x is in a different function. Keeps saying that x is not declared. Is there any way to fix this?

```
class game{

    public:
        void Starter(){
                string z {"Test"};
                z = x;
        }

    private:
        void Questions(){
                string x;
                cout << "Welcome to this game, please answer with yes or no: \n \n";
```

Comment: Please provide the rest of the code (at least the rest of the `Questions()` method).

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I am trying to make it so that z in Starter function is equal x in the Questions function. Not in the same function

Comment: There are many ways around this. To suggest the correct one to use here we need more information. You may even find the best way to get the behaviour you want is to do something completely different. Try to think of programs in terms of behaviours, not code. The code comes later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `x` to `z`.

```
void Starter(string x){
    string z {"Test"};
    z = x;
}
```

Then in your other function you can do `Starter(x);`

Comment: I did that, but then it would stop at z = x and wouldn't print cout which is in the private function.

I might be doing something wrong

Comment: @Sound Try to describe the task you are trying to solve. So far you are asking how to implement an antipattern.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I am trying to make it so that z in Starter function is equal x in the Questions function not in the same function

Comment: @Sound The variable `x` in the `Questions` method is temporary (unless you make it static). You haven't provide the full body of this function, so it is impossible to understand your intention, but you shall NOT rely on the value of the temporary object. If you wish to make the object persistent, you need to extract it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't access an auto variable of one method from another method. There are many reasons for that: the most obvious is that this variable is always new and is not alive after you exit the function. In your case these methods doesn't call each other, so the lifetime of `z` and `x` even doesn't overlap.

What you probably need is a persistent variable that can be seen from both functions. There is a multiple choice for you: object field, global variable, static member...

Your code doesn't describe your intention, but I guess that the right choice for you is a data member:

```
class game{

    public:
        void Starter(){
                string z {"Test"};
                z = x; // You can access x here because it is a data member `this->x`;
        }

    private:
        string x;

        void Questions(){
                cout << "Welcome to this game, please answer with yes or no: \n \n";
                // Do whatever you want with x
        }
};
```